# Crystal Reports XI- blank last page

Tags: crystal-reports-xi

I have a report with 2 subreports. When the 1st subreport is pretty long (but still leaving a good few cm on the page) and the 2nd empty, I often get an extra page printed with only page header and footer.
The subreports and sections are set to be suppressed when blank and it seems to work: I tested this by setting different colours to them and they don't appear. The strange thing is that when I set the section with 2nd subreport to be suppressed for good, the blank page is not printed.

I already switched the New Page After for all the sections, added Not OnLastRecord formula to it and suppressed or deleted all the empty sections in the subreports and around them and still no luck.

I would appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple things you could check that aren't addressed in your question:

1. right click on your subreport and select "Format Subreport"
2. on the common tab, uncheck the box that says "Keep Object Together"
3. on the Subreport tab, in case you are suppressing it another way, check the
       box that says "Suppress Blank Subreport".

I hope this helps.